# Unknown Column Haversine Query with Column created as Query runs

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of results that looks like this (there is only 1 result at the moment):
[image]

Here is my query that produces that result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
ID, post_author, post_title, post_type, post_status,
max(CASE WHEN escort_details.`meta_key` = 'longitude' THEN
escort_details.meta_value END) AS longitude,
max(CASE WHEN escort_details.`meta_key` = 'latitude' THEN
escort_details.meta_value END) AS latitude
FROM wp_posts as escorts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as escort_details
WHERE escorts.post_type = 'escorts'
AND escorts.post_status = 'publish'
```

I'm creating the longitude and latitude columns as the query is run but I want to search those columns and return the distance with the other part of my query which is the haversine part.

So my full query now looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
ID, post_author, post_title, post_type, post_status,
max(CASE WHEN escort_details.`meta_key` = 'longitude' THEN
escort_details.meta_value END) AS longitude,
max(CASE WHEN escort_details.`meta_key` = 'latitude' THEN
escort_details.meta_value END) AS latitude,
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians("121.184006") ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
* cos( radians( longitude ) - radians("14.817371") )
+ sin( radians("121.184006") ) * sin(radians(latitude)) ) ) AS distance
FROM wp_posts as escorts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as escort_details
WHERE escorts.post_type = 'escorts'
AND escorts.post_status = 'publish'
```

The error I am receiving back is "Unknown column 'longitude' in 'field list'" which would make sense as there isn't really a longitude field in the database as it sort of gets created as the query is run.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to combat this?

As always any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Codarz360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the alias on doing a different calculation. One way is to write a outer query to get the list of fields and then do the calculation

```
select
distinct
ID, post_author, post_title, post_type, post_status,longitude,latitude,
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians("121.184006") ) * cos( radians( longitude ) ) 
* cos( radians( latitude ) - radians("14.817371") )
+ sin( radians("121.184006") ) * sin(radians(longitude)) ) ) AS distance
from (
 SELECT  
 ID, post_author, post_title, post_type, post_status,
 max(CASE WHEN escort_details.`meta_key` = 'longitude' THEN
 escort_details.meta_value END) AS longitude,
 max(CASE WHEN escort_details.`meta_key` = 'latitude' THEN
 escort_details.meta_value END) AS latitude
 FROM wp_posts as escorts 
 INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as escort_details
 WHERE escorts.post_type = 'escorts'
 AND escorts.post_status = 'publish'
)x
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I now receive the error "FUNCTION theescorts.latitude does not exist" do I need to add a function to the database or something?

Comment: Check of you have a comma after `latitude,` in the outer select, I had a typo which I fixed.

Comment: Awesome man thanks so much for your help that has appeared to work and I'll mark you answer as correct. I only seem to be getting 1 result back although I know I have multiple entries in the database you wouldn't be any chance happen to know why this is would you? Once again thanks so much!

Comment: Add a `group by ID` at the end of inner query, you are using aggregate function `max` if no group by specified then it will return only one row.

Comment: Great thanks man I sort of figured it when I commented. I do seem to be getting back the same latitude, longitude and distance for each of the results even though I do know that they are different, would this be something related to the GROUP BY again? Sorry for all the questions but think I'm nearly there.

Comment: Hmm and you are getting different `longitude` but same `latitude` ? The pivot query looks good i.e. the inner part. What if you just run the inner query and see what it returns ? Perhaps the answer lies in there. Also note that you have a join clause `INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as escort_details` But I do not see a joining condition, you should use `INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as escort_details on escorts.somekey = wp_postmeta.somekey`, In WP they are joined via ID.

Comment: Ah thanks man I seemed to fix that issue now it just seems that the distance is incorrect and it's returning like 5020.7691711194675 for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for your help dude but any reason the distances would just be completely incorrect?

Comment: Ah not to worry I fixed that now the latitude and longitude was the reverse way around